# Stretch a QTableWidget column, but allow user to resize if needed

Tags: qt, resize, qtablewidget

I'm seeking for a way to stretch a QTableWidget column, but still allow user to resize if needed. When I stretch a column using

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

user is unable to resize the column. Here is a sketch of what I need.

[image: Table Sketch]

Comment: Important point is how do you set the 100px wide, if it is fixed it's normal that you cannot resize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this method:

1. After table initialization and when it's filled with data set resizeMode to QHeaderView::Stretch
2. Walk through header columns, and store their width's to some array. 
   The widths of columns is accessible by:

`ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->sectionSize(i)`

3. Set resizeMode to QHeaderView::Interactive, and set widths of columns to what you've stored at previous step.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I am just letting here the code for resize the column, in case someone is looking for it:
`ui->tableWidget->setColumnWidth(i, storedScretchSize);`